# Bunch of compilation errors in cmath when building C code in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, compilation

I'm trying to compile C code in VS2010. When I do, I get 714 errors in cmath, a file I haven't even included.

Here are the included files:  http://pastebin.com/LzsDfEcr

The errors are all the same "style", e.g:

```
Error   711 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ceil'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath    40
Error   712 error C2059: syntax error : ';' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath    40
```

and then the same two errors just with another identifier.

I have Compile As C on under C/C++ -> Advanced, and all the files in the project are .c files.

Comment: The answers below are correct, I just can't seem to mark them as answers. All in all it was me being stupid - I am converting a C++ project to C, and I haven't worked with C/C++ in a long time. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`<cmath>` is a C++ header file.  It's probably being included by some other C++ header file.  Looking at your code, I can see that you're including `<string>` and `<sstream>`, both of which are C++ header files.

Answer (score 1):

```
//#include <unistd.h> // doesn't exist in vs2010?
```

unistd.h is a unix header